# How do I remove the legends from plot_roc_curve?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using a ROC with cross validation code posted on [Scikit API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html):

There is a part of the code that reads:

```
viz = plot_roc_curve(classifier, X[test], y[test],
                         name='ROC fold {}'.format(i),
                         alpha=0.3, lw=1, ax=ax)
```

I would like to keep the ROC curves for multiple fold, and the legend for the mean and chance, but want to remove the legend on the corner of the figure. But when I change part of the code to:

```
viz = plot_roc_curve(classifier, X[test], y[test],
                         alpha=0.3, lw=1, ax=ax)
```

It will just replace that fold in the legend with the classifier.

Is there anyway to remove the legends, but keep the curves?

Full script is copy and pasted below. And what the image looks like:

[Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) with cross validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhQxh.png)

Again, I would just like to remove the legend for the folds, but keep their ROC, and the legends for mean and chance. Is there anyway to handle this without changing the code completely?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import auc
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

# #############################################################################
# Data IO and generation

# Import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
n_samples, n_features = X.shape

# Add noisy features
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

# #############################################################################
# Classification and ROC analysis

# Run classifier with cross-validation and plot ROC curves
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6)
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                     random_state=random_state)

tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv.split(X, y)):
    classifier.fit(X[train], y[train])
    viz = plot_roc_curve(classifier, X[test], y[test],
                         name='ROC fold {}'.format(i),
                         alpha=0.3, lw=1, ax=ax)
    interp_tpr = interp(mean_fpr, viz.fpr, viz.tpr)
    interp_tpr[0] = 0.0
    tprs.append(interp_tpr)
    aucs.append(viz.roc_auc)

ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r',
        label='Chance', alpha=.8)

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
std_auc = np.std(aucs)
ax.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b',
        label=r'Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)' % (mean_auc, std_auc),
        lw=2, alpha=.8)

std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
ax.fill_between(mean_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=.2,
                label=r'$\pm$ 1 std. dev.')

ax.set(xlim=[-0.05, 1.05], ylim=[-0.05, 1.05],
       title="Receiver operating characteristic example")
ax.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

### Easy with a bit of hacking on the legends:

```
# Here is the trick
plt.gcf()
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = handles[6:]
labels = labels[6:]
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
plt.show()
```

**Full code:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import auc
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

# #############################################################################
# Data IO and generation

# Import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
n_samples, n_features = X.shape

# Add noisy features
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

# #############################################################################
# Classification and ROC analysis

# Run classifier with cross-validation and plot ROC curves
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6)
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                     random_state=random_state)

tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv.split(X, y)):
    classifier.fit(X[train], y[train])
    viz = plot_roc_curve(classifier, X[test], y[test],
                         name='ROC fold {}'.format(i),
                         alpha=0.3, lw=1, ax=ax)
    interp_tpr = interp(mean_fpr, viz.fpr, viz.tpr)
    interp_tpr[0] = 0.0
    tprs.append(interp_tpr)
    aucs.append(viz.roc_auc)

ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r',
        label='Chance', alpha=.8)

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
std_auc = np.std(aucs)
ax.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b',
        label=r'Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)' % (mean_auc, std_auc),
        lw=2, alpha=.8)

std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
ax.fill_between(mean_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=.2,
                label=r'$\pm$ 1 std. dev.')

ax.set(xlim=[-0.05, 1.05], ylim=[-0.05, 1.05],
       title="Receiver operating characteristic example")
ax.legend(loc="lower right")

# Here is the trick
plt.gcf()
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = handles[6:]
labels = labels[6:]
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

since you have the matplotlib axes (`ax`) at the end, you can tweak it by the following way.

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax.legend(handles[-3:], labels[-3:])
ax.get_figure()
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to keep the chance and mean in the legend. Just remove the ROC folds from the legend.